# Testing StructureMap convention

Tags: c#, unit-testing, structuremap

I have a convention for StructureMap that looks like this:

```
public class FakeRepositoriesConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, global::StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry registry)
   {
        if (type.Name.StartsWith("Fake") && type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
        {
            string interfaceName = "I" + type.Name.Replace("Fake", String.Empty);
            registry.AddType(type.GetInterface(interfaceName), type);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to implement unit tests for this, but I don't know how to do that.

My first thought was to send in a mocked Registry and just test that AddType() is called with the right parameters. I can't get that to work though, probably because AddType() is not virtual. Registry implements IRegistry but that doesn't help me since the Process method doesn't accept an interface.

**So my question is - how can I test this?**

*(I'm using nUnit and RhinoMocks)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip mocking altogether and use simplified version of your registry and component with predefined dummy types:

```
// Dummy types for test usage only
public interface ICorrectRepository { }
public class FakeCorrectRepository : ICorrectRepository { }

[Test]
Process_RegistersFakeRepositoryType_ThroughInterfaceTypeName()
{
    var registry = new Registry();
    var convention = new FakeRepositoriesConvention();

    // exercise test
    convention.Process(typeof(FakeCorrectRepository), registry);

    // assert it worked
    var container = new Container(c => c.AddRegistry(registry));
    var instance = container.GetInstance<ICorrectRepository>();
    Assert.That(instance, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

If your convention works as you assume it does, test above should pass.